# looking for iOS button image samples

Tags: iphone, ios

is there a library or something to get iPhone and iPad button images like add, delete, new contact, ...

i can't really find anything about that, but there has to be something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in elements you are looking for are at the [bottom of this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html)

Comment: Specific section: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#Standard Buttons for Use in Toolbars and Navigation Bars

Answer (score 2):

For toolbars and tab bars, there's [glyphish](http://glyphish.com).

Comment: but isn't there a way to use the standard iOS button images?